# Creating an environment variable for a specific user

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell

When you set an environment variable in linux is it set only for the user who executes it, or can you specify a user when you store it, or instead is it always available for all users?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to know if I can set an env var for a single user, so that if it tries to be recalled by another user it cannot be

Answer (score 2):

If you set environment variables in the global shell startup scripts, they'll be applied to all users who log in.  The location of these scripts depends on the shells, but common locations are /etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d, /etc/bashrc, and /etc/X11/Xsession.d.  You need to read the manuals for your shell(s)/desktop environments to find out for sure.  For example, for bash see the section "INVOCATION" in the bash manual.

To set an environment variable for just a single user, you could either set it in that user's startup scripts (~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.xsessionrc, ...), or in the global startup scripts with a test to apply it only to that user.

Comment: Can you tell apply it to one user only if that user does not have a home directory?

Comment: A simple line in  your Global profile like this perhaps  `[ "$USER" = 'jwillson' ] && export foo=blah`.

Comment: You could also look at pam_env http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env

Answer (score 1):

You can set a user's variable in their ( /home/user ) .profile or .bashrc , they will be set at (Bash) login time and they won't be set for other users.